# React Native testing with axe: All page content should be contained by landmarks (region)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to introduce accessibility testing with `jest-axe`.

Only thing is that I'm using `JSX` instead of `html`, so my first question is if it's possible to use axe along with `JSX` components.

If it's possible, what's the action to take to solve the error:

> "All page content should be contained by landmarks (region)" ?

I'm trying a sample component to begin with:

```
        <View>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
        </View>
```

And using axe to test for accessibility errors:

```
describe("Sample Component", () => {
    it("Should check for accessibility issues", () => {
        const wrapper = mount(
            <SampleComponent></SampleComponent>
          );
          const results = await axe(wrapper.getDOMNode());
      
          expect(results).toHaveNoViolations();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

At time of writing 02-06-2022

Axe isn't compatible with react-native as [Aryella Lacerda highlights in her article](https://medium.com/reactbrasil/introducing-react-native-accessibility-engine-fcf78f2a3805)

> However, Axe only supports HTML-based languages, which unfortunately excludes React Native.

Fortunately she has created [React Native Accessibility Engine](https://github.com/aryella-lacerda/react-native-accessibility-engine)
which is a testing library which allows you to make assertions about accessibility leveraging the [React Native Accessibility API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibility). It integrate with jest to make adding accessibility test to existing tests a breeze. Her article also includes strategies for making react native apps accessible.

[This article](https://www.shopify.com.au/partners/blog/react-native-accessibility) by Scott Vinkle is another great resource for creating accessible react native apps.